# Leaderboard "My Circles" not showing player's friends

Tags: google-play-services

I have been integrating the Games Services APIs into my games for a few days now and having a weird problem that can possibly qualify as a bug.

So I've setup a few test players with Gmail accounts and have added them to each other's circles. The problem I am having is that when I start the activity with the leaderboard's intent the "My Circles" tab doesn't show the other players in the current player's circles, even though the players show up on the Public tab.

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

A couple months late, but, considering I've recently run into the exact same problem, I figure I'll post my findings to aid anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future.

I'm assuming that you're still in the **testing** phase and haven't actually **published** your game via the Google Play Developer Console. **Publishing is the key**.  There are two tiny sentences buried in a NOTE on this Google developer page:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#creating_a_leaderboard

> Note: Social leaderboards will initially be empty until you publish
>   the corresponding leaderboard by using the Google Play Developer
>   Console

Social leaderboards won't be useful until **after** you publish. i.e. You'll never see social leaderboards during testing.

Comment: I published for alpha testing but still see only myself in the social leaderboard ... friends appear only when i switch from social to all in the leaderboard ... any idea?